# Add object and list of object inside another list c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a list of List of Object and an object inside another list, for example;

```
public Class TeamRoles
{
    public Team Team{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Role> Roles{get;set;}
}
```

I am looping through another list of type TeamRoles and want to add each of that object after some modifications inside the List of TeamRoles, something like below;

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var teamsRoles = _client.GetAllTeamEmployeeRoles();
    var distinctTeams = teamsRoles.Select(x => x.Team).Distinct();
    var tRoles = new List<TeamRoles>();
    foreach (var team in distinctTeams)
    {
        var t = team;
        var roles = teamsRoles.Where(x => x.TeamId ==team.Id).Select(y => y.Role);
        tRoles.Add(new { t, roles}); //need this
    }
}
```

Please help me if you understand my question and ask for more info if you don't. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What help you are looking for?? Which piece of the code seems to be not working upto ur expectations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate the TeamRoles and assign values to it, something like this:

```
var teamRoles = new TeamRoles
 {
   Roles = roles,
   Team = t
 };

tRoles.Add(teamRoles); //need this
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what your question is (is it that your program doesn't compile?)

You need to instantiate `TeamRoles` like

```
    foreach (var team in distinctTeams)
    {

        var t = team;
        var roles = teamsRoles.Where(x => x.TeamId ==team.Id).Select(y => y.Role);
        tRoles.Add(new TeamRoles { Team=t, Roles=roles }); //need this  <====
     }
```